# Why is this React component page not rendering correctly when an id is passed via the React Router URL?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm using the following dependencies for React:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
"react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
"react-icons": "^3.11.0",
"react-live-clock": "^4.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3"
```

I have a menu where I load a component `PageHowtos` with and without a passed id:

```
<Route exact path="/howtos" render={() => <PageHowtos {...this.state.pageProps} />} />
<Route exact path="/howtos/:id" render={() => <PageHowtos {...this.state.pageProps} />} />
```

When I don't send an id in the URL, the page renders fine:

[image]

But when I send an id in the URL, the page receives the id, but it doesn't render correctly:

[image]

This is the PageHowtos.tsx page:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import 'custom/styles/pageHowtos.scss';

const pageTitle = 'Web Developer > Howtos';

interface IProps {
    changeSiteTitle: any
}

interface ParamTypes {
 id: string
}

function PageHowtos(props: IProps) {
    const { id } = useParams<ParamTypes>();
    useEffect(() => {
        props.changeSiteTitle(pageTitle);
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="page_howtos">
            <Helmet>
                <title>Howtos</title>
            </Helmet>
            <div>
                This is the Howtos page. From URL, id = {id}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PageHowtos;
```

**What could be causing the page not to render correctly when an id is passed in the URL?**

## ADDENDUM

**It seems that when the `id` is passed, the page does not load the Bootstrap styles (!). Why could that be?**

[image]

Comment: What is incorrect about how it is rendered?

Comment: @im_baby I marked up the second image above to highlight what is not being rendered correctly, i.e. the button styles are somewhat missing, the icon is not correctly positioned. But looking in the rendered HTML/CSS in the browser, I see no difference between the two pages.

Comment: I thought that it could be that the `id` string variable had some HTML it which caused malrendering, but I determined this is not the case.

Comment: It seems to be not loading the stylesheet correctly in the parent file, as if the extra `/` in the URL messes with the path to the stylesheet.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay can you try switching the order of your routes? put the one with :id first.

Comment: Ok, I found something interesting: It seems that when the `id` is passed, the page does not load the Bootstrap styles (see added screenshot). Why could that be?

Comment: although, I'm not sure if `exact` plays well with wildcards, try removing `exact` from `/howtos/:id` route.

Comment: Thanks @LuisSardon, I had thought of that, switching the order of the routes in the parent file has no effect. The issue is that when sending the `id`, it doesn't load the Bootstrap styles. Why would that be?

Comment: @LuisSardon Taking exact out also has no effect.

Comment: Any chance we can see the styles?

Comment: I think the issue is not in the pages you are rendering, which look fine, something else at an upper level is going on.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the answer: needed a preceding slash in the path to my Bootstrap libraries being loading in my `index.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It had nothing to do with React-Router as such.

I was loading my Bootstrap files with a relative path and needed a preceding slash!

[image]